# Uploading a file with Django REST framework ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django REST framework's generic `ListCreateAPIView`, I've created an end point that I think should be able to upload photos via POST requests. I am modeling my code on [this tutorial](http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html).

So far I have attempted to POST a file to this endpoint using both Android and curl, and observed the same behavior: a new record is created, but the file is not attached. Because the file is a required field, the server then returns a 500 error.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303252/django-rest-framework-imagefield?rq=1) looks similar, but he's not using REST framework's generic views and I'm not sure why... I'd like to take advantage of them where applicable.

Here is my Django view:

```python
class PhotoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Photo
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
```

...my model:

```
def get_unique_image_file_path(instance=None, filename='dummy.jpg'):
    """
    function to determine where to save images.  assigns a uuid (random string) to each and places it
    in the images subdirectory below media.  by default, we assume the file is a .jpg
    """
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    # TODO: 'images' is hard coded
    return os.path.join('images', filename)

class Photo(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='photos', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_unique_image_file_path)

    def get_image_abs_path(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name)
```

... and my serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.Field('image.url')

class Meta:
    model = Photo
```

### Reproducing the bug

To generate the behavior, I POST to the server using the following `curl` command (exactly the same thing happens with my Android client code):

```
curl --form image=@test_image.jpg http://localhost:8000/rest_tutorial/photos
```

Looking into `generics.ListCreateAPIView`, the `create()` method looks like this:

```
# Copied from rest_framework.mixins.CreateModelMixin 

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        self.pre_save(serializer.object)
        self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
        self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As I step through the above code in PyCharm's debugger, I can clearly see my file in the serializer's `init_files` field after `serializer.get_serializer()`. However, serializer's `object` field has a bunch of tracebacks but no references to my image file. Maybe something is wrong here?

After `self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)` the record is created with an empty image field, the file is  not uploaded, and `self.object.image.file` just contains a traceback referring to a `ValueError`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your serializer class where you define the `image` model field as `Field`. The generic `Field` is read-only, so that may be the source of the problem. Try simply removing that from your serializer, as it isn't necessary:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

Hope this helps, let me know how you get along.