# How to properly upload images when also sending data to the server

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented an view that is for registering an organization. How do I successfully upload files given the following payload:

```
{
"admin":{
        "username":"kapyjovu@abyssmail.com",
        "first_name":"Cindy",
        "last_name":"Georgia",
        "password":"password",
        "email":"kapyjovu@abyssmail.com"
    },
"org":{
        "name":"ARIZONA LAW SOCIETY",
        "short_name":"ALS",
        "tag_line":"ALS",
        "email":"kapyjovu@abyssmail.com",
        "company_phone": "+2540000000",
        "po_box": "200",
        "location":"NAKURU",
        "first_logo": "https://www.mintformations.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/shutterstock_583717939.jpg",
        "second_logo": "https://www.mintformations.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/shutterstock_583717939.jpg",
        "third_logo": "https://www.mintformations.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/shutterstock_583717939.jpg"
    }
}
```

```
class OrganizationRegistration(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = OrgRegistrationSerializer

    """End point to register organization"""

    def post(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            admins = Group.objects.get(name__iexact='admin')
            admin_role = Role.objects.get(name__iexact="admin")
            
        except:
            # the admin group is
            admins = Group.objects.create(name="admin")

            admin_role = Role.objects.create(name="admin")

           
        # finally:
        try:
            admin = User.objects.create(
                username=request.data['admin']['username'],
                email=request.data['admin']['email'],
                first_name=request.data['admin']['first_name'],
                last_name=request.data['admin']['last_name'],
            )


            
            location_name = request.data['org']['location'].upper()
        
            location_obj, _  = Location.objects.get_or_create(name=location_name)
            area_name = location_obj.name
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e)
            return Response(data={"msg":str(e),"success":False, "data": None},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # admin.set_password(request.data['admin']['password'])


        try: 

            
            # Create Random Password   
            password = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10)
            admin.set_password(password)
            admin.save()
            # add the user creating the Organization to the admin group
            # admins.user_set.add(admin)
            admin.groups.add(admins)
            admin.roles.add(admin_role)


            first_file_logo = request.data['org']['first_logo']
            second_file_logo = request.data['org']['second_logo']
            third_file_logo = request.data['org']['third_logo']

            org = Organization.objects.create(
                name=request.data['org']['name'],
                email=request.data['org']['email'],
                location=request.data['org']['location'],
                short_name = request.data['org']['short_name'],
                tag_line = request.data['org']['tag_line'],
                company_phone =  request.data['org']['company_phone'],
                po_box = request.data['org']['po_box'],
                first_logo = first_file_logo,
                second_logo =second_file_logo ,
                third_logo =  third_file_logo
            )

            
            admin.org_id = org.id
            admin.save()
            # add the user creating the Organization to admins by DEFAULT
            # NOTE:
            # all the other normaall users will be added normally i.e
            admins.save()
            org.admin.add(admin)
            org.user_set.add(admin)
            admin.is_active = False
            admin.save()
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(admin, org)
            jwt_token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            support_email = settings.SUPPORT_EMAIL
            # # FIXME:
            # refactor this code inorder to have its own function
            path = get_full_path(request)

            path = settings.BASE_URL
            subject = 'Welcome onboard E-vote'
            # if the org is regestering themselves the org id will alway be zero
            message = 'Follow\n {}sso/registration/confirmation/{}/ \nto complete \
                the sign-up process. \nAfter Confirmation your Login Password is: {}'.format(
                path, jwt_token.decode("utf-8"),password)

            # print(path+'/api/sso/registration/confirmation/{}'.format(jwt_token.decode("utf-8") ))
            # invitation sent to organization
            mail_sent_to_org = send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                support_email,
                [org.email]
            )

            message = 'Follow\n{}sso/registration/confirmation/{}/ \nto complete \
                the sign-up process. \nAfter Confirmation your Login Password use this Password: {}'.format(
                path, jwt_token.decode("utf-8") ,password)
            # invitation sent to admin
            mail_sent_to_admin = send_mail(
                subject,
                message,
                support_email,
                [admin.email]
            )
            serializer = OrgRegSerializer(org)
            res = {"msg": "Check personal and organization emails, NOTE: finish org registration first!!!", "success": True, "data": serializer.data}
            return Response(
                data=res,
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(data={"msg":str(e),"success":False, "data": None},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Models**

```
class Organization(Group):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='org_users')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    tag_line = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    company_phone =  models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    po_box = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    first_logo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    second_logo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    third_logo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Comment: You can't directly pass url to image field while creating object. You have to open the image file in read mode or read only mode and pass that to django model field. This will provide some ways to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield

Comment: @SivaSankar the links were just an example. so if I replace the code base where I'm creating an organization to:

```
   serializer_org = OrganizationSerializer(data=payload)

   if serializer_org.is_valid():
      serializer_org.save()
```
This should work as long I send the valid data.

Comment: You should do something like this serializer org = OrganizationSerializer(data=payload, files=request.FILES), check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303252/django-rest-framework-imagefield